# java adding two int arrays with different lengths. why giving a result that is smaller than correct result?

Tags: java

```
public void add(int[]a1,int[]a2){       

    int atotal[] = new int[20];
    int capacity3 = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity3; i++) 
    {
      int a3 = a1[i] + a2[i];
      if (a3 > 9)
      {
        atotal[i] = a3 % 10;
        atotal[i+1] += a3 /10;
      }
      else
      {
        atotal[i] = a3;
      }
    } 

    for(int i = capacity3 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      System.out.print(atotal[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

In the addition of each elements in two arrays in my program, the carry of each single bit addition is not added to the next-insignificance bit .
so if array1[0] = 9, array2[0] = 2.. my result[0] = 1 and my result[1] doesn't have the added one from [0].
for example if i put 9999 and 1234 as the two arrays ,the result is 0123 instead of 11233.

Comment: lol, this code formatting is atrocious.

Comment: This will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you even try to use 2 arrays with different lengths

Comment: @Djon If the max length is greater than 20, it should do it.

Comment: I fixed a lot of the formatting but... friend, you gotta use some white space, put your brackets on lines by themselves, etc.  Also, use meaningful names for your variables.

Comment: sorry about the formatting,it's my first time posting here.and also thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you place the carry in `atotal[i+1]` then you completely ignore the value on the next loop.

To fix this you could just add `atotal[i]` to `a3`.

```
int a3 = a1[i] + a2[i] + atotal[i];
```

Then inside the if statement you don't really need to do `+=` here `atotal[i+1] += a3 / 10;`  because `atotal[i+1]` is always 0 and it is wiped on the next loop so it could just be `=`.

Lastly your for loop could be missing the very first digit if there is a carry. To fix this you could just start `i` at capacity3 but in some cases you will print a leading 0.

So calling `add(new int[]{9,9,9,9}, new int[]{4,3,2,1});` with these fixes produces

```
1 1 2 3 3
```

So the fixed code might look something like this.

```
public static void add(int[]a1,int[]a2){       
    int atotal[] = new int[20];
    int capacity3 = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity3; i++) {
        int a3 = a1[i] + a2[i] + atotal[i];
        System.out.println(a3);
        if(a3>9) {
            atotal[i] = a3 % 10;
            atotal[i+1] = a3 / 10;
        } else {
            atotal[i]=a3;
        }
    } 
    for(int i=capacity3; i>=0; i--) {
        System.out.print(atotal[i] + " ");
    }
}
```